# (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

After successfully deploying a container using `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/projectname/testserver` and then attempting to run `gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/projectname/testserver --platform managed` I see this error:

```
$ gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/projectname/testserver --platform managed
Please specify a region:
 // options removed

Service name (testserver):  
Allow unauthenticated invocations to [testserver] (y/N)?  y

Deploying container to Cloud Run service [testserver] in project [projectname] region [us-central1]
X Deploying new service... Cloud Run error:
 Container failed to start. Failed to start
 and then listen on the port defined by the
 PORT environment variable. Logs for this r
evision might contain more information.    
  X Creating Revision... Cloud Run error: C
  ontainer failed to start. Failed to start
   and then listen on the port defined by t
  he PORT environment variable. Logs for th
  is revision might contain more informatio
  n.                                       
  . Routing traffic...                     
  ✓ Setting IAM Policy...                  
Deployment failed                          
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

I have a very simple project, all in the root folder:

```
// Dockerfile
FROM node:12-slim

# Create app folder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app deps. Copy the lock file
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . ./
CMD ["node", "testServer.js"]
```

```
// testServer.js
const Koa = require("koa");
const koa = new Koa();

koa.get('/', async ctx => {
  ctx.body = "Koa server running"
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

koa.listen(port);
```

Anyone know what's causing this? Been trying to solve it since yesterday and now even with this minimal project it seems to be having issues.

Comment: What if any errors are being logged from the startup of the container?   Can you collect all your artifacts and put them in a temporary GitHub repo and post the link.  Maybe some kind soul might attempt a recreate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received `TypeError: app.get is not a function` with your code. Looks like this syntax is obsolete. Rewrote with [koa-router](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router#new-routeropts) and worked just fine.

Anyway try to test your code locally with [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) before deploying.
And also you can find more precise error messages during deployment in console-> logging-> cloud run revision-> revision_id

Comment: thank you, I solved this particular issue. I have another issue now though, and `docker run ..` doesn't work. Does `..` stand for something else?

Comment: @SeanDezoysa, Updated the answer with reference to `docker run`.

Answer (score 1):

Same error here. I solved that increasing the `timeout`.